# Is there a way to configure multiple Serilog RollingFiles through appSetting configuration

Tags: serilog

Is there a way to configure multiple Serilog RollingFiles through appSetting?

I want to create separate log files for Information and Error levels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly - it's possible to use a setting prefix like:

```
.ReadFrom.AppSettings()
.ReadFrom.AppSettings(settingPrefix: "2")
```

And then add the additional sink like:

```
<add key="2:serilog:write-to:RollingFile.pathFormat" value="..." />
```

Baking this properly into the app settings configuration provider has been a "TODO" for a while.

If configuring the sinks in code is possible, that's probably the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried but it didn't work, though you pointed me in the right direction.  
I had to look at the code to figure out why it was not picking up the configuration. The code is:  
` _settingPrefix = settingPrefix == null ? "serilog:" : string.Format("{0}:serilog:", settingPrefix); `
So I had to supply the prefix as follows:
<add key="custom:serilog:write-to:RollingFile.pathFormat" value="..." />

Comment: In the above comment "custom" is the prefix used in the API ie.    
'.ReadFrom.AppSettings(settingPrefix: "custom")`

Comment: Thanks - fixed the example.

Comment: Hi @NicholasBlumhardt - per your comment above, does the AppSettings package support this yet? Thanks

Comment: Hey @RobDavis - no, though the JSON configuration syntax doesn't suffer this issue.

Comment: @NicholasBlumhardt But how would you do this in JSON? Adding two RollingFile sinks in appsettings.json for a ASP.NET core project throws a 'same key already added to dictionary' exception, how would I apply the prefix there?

Comment: @Chris Hi! Might be a good topic for another question (TBH I'm not sure, and would need to look into it). Cheers!

Comment: @NicholasBlumhardt I checked out the code and changed the return type for GetMethodCalls from a dictionary to a list of KeyValuePairs. Works like a charm.

Comment: Any idea why switching from hard-coded `.WriteTo.RollingFile  ...`  to `.ReadFrom.AppSettings` works locally but when I publish and deploy to remote server, it doesn't work? (Note that it works on the remote server when I hard code it `.WriteTo.RollingFile    ....`

Answer (score 4):

Configuring multiple logs is pretty simple in appsettings, mission is to use filter. i spent almost 3hours trying to figure out how to archieve this.

I ended up doing the following:

**Startup.cs / Global.asax.cs**

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
           .WriteTo
           .Logger(x => x.Filter
           .ByIncludingOnly(logEvent => logEvent.Level == Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Error)
           .ReadFrom
           .AppSettings("error"))

           .WriteTo
           .Logger(x => x.Filter
           .ByIncludingOnly(logEvent => logEvent.Level == Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Information)
           .ReadFrom
           .AppSettings("info")).CreateLogger()
```

**Web.Config**

```
<add key ="error:serilog:using:RollingFile" value="Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile"/>
<add key ="error:serilog:write-to:RollingFile.pathFormat" value="C:\log\error {Date}.txt"/>
<add key ="error:serilog:write-to:RollingFile.formatter" value="Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter"/>

<add key ="info:serilog:using:RollingFile" value="Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile"/>
<add key ="info:serilog:write-to:RollingFile.pathFormat" value="C:\log\info {Date}.txt"/>
<add key ="info:serilog:write-to:RollingFile.formatter" value="Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter"/>
```