# Is there a way to configure Serilog sub loggers via configuration file?

Tags: asp.net, serilog

Currently I have all configuration written in code. I use subloggers for filtering and changing the storage of logging. Is there any way to do it from configuration file. Because I want to have a separate config file for every context in solution.

Comment: This might be useful, [question]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41989190/7038900

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number of sub-loggers is fixed at build time, you can use configuration prefixes to do this:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.AppSettings() // default file
    .WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc
        .ReadFrom.AppSettings(filePath: "other1.config"))             
    .WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc
        .ReadFrom.AppSettings(filePath: "other2.config"))
    .CreateLogger();
```

There's no support in Serilog.Settings.AppSettings yet, but in theory there's nothing preventing it being added if someone's able to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**Startup.cs / Global.asax.cs**

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
           .WriteTo
           .Logger(x => x.Filter
           .ByIncludingOnly(logEvent => logEvent.Level == Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Error)
           .ReadFrom
           .AppSettings("error"))

           .WriteTo
           .Logger(x => x.Filter
           .ByIncludingOnly(logEvent => logEvent.Level == Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Information)
           .ReadFrom
           .AppSettings("info")).CreateLogger()
```

**Web.Config**

```
<add key ="error:serilog:using:RollingFile" value="Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile"/>
<add key ="error:serilog:write-to:RollingFile.pathFormat" value="C:\log\error {Date}.txt"/>
<add key ="error:serilog:write-to:RollingFile.formatter" value="Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter"/>

<add key ="info:serilog:using:RollingFile" value="Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile"/>
<add key ="info:serilog:write-to:RollingFile.pathFormat" value="C:\log\info {Date}.txt"/>
<add key ="info:serilog:write-to:RollingFile.formatter" value="Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter"/>
```

Comment: Please don't add [the same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41989190/4687348) to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/347985)